# How to get last inserted record id in joomla Breezingforms extension

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, breezingforms

I have inserted record in joomla users table using this extension and I want to assign group to last inserted user. So ho can I do that. Is it possible to fetch last inserted id and insert record in #__user_groupmap for assign usergroup to user.

How can I use. Integrator > Finalize Code. (see attachment)
I tried to find out tutorial for that on your site but there is no example for that.

Comment: There is no attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **Manage Pieces** option there is multiple types. Like Before form, After form, Being submit, End Submit see in attached image. Select type and you can insert your code in **code field** . I have put some link below they maybe help you more.

https://crosstec.org/en/component/finder/search.html?q=Pieces&f=1&Itemid=146

https://crosstec.org/en/support/online-documentation/breezingforms/10-advanced-settings/213-script-and-pieces.html

https://crosstec.org/en/support/online-documentation/breezingforms/12-examples-scripts/740-new-register-or-login-to-complete-form.html

[image]